# Should "universal pedals" be avoided?

Tags: repair, safety, parts, pedals, pedals-flat

Are universal pedal axles weaker than standard axles? If so, should they be avoided?

These are inexpensive pedals so let's focus on inexpensive normal, solid axles vs these universal pedals.

[image]

Each pedal comes with a 1/2 inch and a 9/16 inch adapter that must be screwed into the pedal body.

The left pedal adapter threads in with a left hand thread, the right pedal adapter threads in with a right hand thread.

---

**Edit 4/10/2020**

Would they be strong enough for any of the following applications?

Could these pedals be strong enough for some applications not displayed below?

The following bikes were chosen because they come from *bike shops* with *roughly comparable inexpensive plastic pedals*.

All the bikes are Trek because it was easy to find a wide variety of Trek bicycles. This is not meant as an endorsement of Trek.

Option 1: Trek Tag Along
[image]

Option 2: Trek cruiser
[image]

Option 3: Trek children's bike
[image]

Option 4: Trek 24 inch wheel bike
[image]

Comment: A good quality pedal axle goes through the pedal from side to side The ones shown here carry the rider's weight on half a dozen threads. They may be good for an emergency replacement in a poorly furnished workshop when nothing better is at hand but certainly not for day to day riding.

Comment: @Carel Technically the pedal is attached to the crank arm with a half dozen threads, so I'm not sure I see that as a big downside assuming the threads are sufficiently tight and the metal is of good quality.

Comment: I've never seen those before and am curious about the small shaft on the end. Does that fit into a hole in the axle in the pedal?

Comment: Definitely not a strong as solid axles. Why use these if you can get normal pedals with the correct thread?

Comment: @Kibbee depends on quality of machining - sure a threadded joint can be super strong, but looking at the plastic pedals, this is not high-quality product.

Comment: Fascinating that this maker has decided providing four extra parts, and performing 8 threading operations is overall cheaper than making two separate axle threads and carrying two different SKUs through their inventory/supply chain.

Comment: @Kibbee: In theory, yes. But then they're cheap pedals = probably not the best steel and not the high quality machining. Wand while standard pedals are secured with a thicker 9/16 thread these will also be secured with what could be a 10mm thread. Allow me to have doubts.

Comment: I can't understand what problem they solve. If one needs 9/16 pedals, get those, if its 1/2" then get those. Who's swapping pedals between adult bikes and kids' bikes?

Comment: @Swifty Same supply chain for kid's BSO pedals and stationary exercise bike pedals?  Those are just about the only two uses I'd think it'd be good for.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No for kids' bikes! Would you let your offspring ride a bike that uses second rate and potentially dangerous parts? Not me. Also because children are mostly not aware at all of an upcoming failure.Here we have two more vital screwed-in parts that may come undone.

Comment: @Carel A 20 kg/40 lb child is never going to put stresses on pedals that an adult will.  A WalMart My Little Pony BSO with 10" wheels probably has a lot more parts of dodgier reliability than pedals like this.

Answer (score 3):

In context of the low cost pedals, you need to look at the user and how they ride. Would I trust them on a trials bike or downhill MTB?, no, but then I would not trust a cheap pedals with a one piece axle.  Would I trust them in a situation I would trust a similar pair of cheap one piece axles, absolutely.

In theory the two piece axle will be less reliable as it has another failure mode that does not exist on a one piece axle. However, the failure of the extra threaded join is probably much less likely than the pedal to crank join, due the thread locker. Therefore, the increased risk is marginal.

So the question is not 'should they be avoided because they have a two piece axle", its "Should cheap pedals be avoided"

Comment: Exactly. Especially since all but the last image in the question show bikes where the cheapest possible pedal will work like a charm. Absolutely no point in using high-end pedals on a child's bike!

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting concept I haven't seen before. In theory they should be as strong as a solid axle. I have never seen a pedal axle break. In any type of collision,  the crank arm usually breaks before the pedal shaft. The thread-lock  on the adapters is a good sign that some thought went into the design. However using two fasteners instead of one doubles the odds of something coming loose. I imagine they would be more expensive than a single size pedal as they require extra machining, but could be useful if you were unsure what size to order.

Comment: re: 'In theory they should be as strong as a solid axle'. I respectfully disagree with that

Comment: "In theory they should be as strong as a solid axle" yeah not even close, not in theory nor in practice.

Comment: The neck of the small threading in the adapter piece will be the weak point. It is submitted to shearing forces and to stretching from being tightened.

Comment: @Carel The pedal will also distort under load around the smaller threads making those forces even worse, something that doesn't happen for a solid-axle pedal.  So that's another weak spot and failure mode that doesn't exist on a solid-axle pedal.  It's a kid's BSO pedal, or maybe a stationary exercise bike pedal.

Comment: I remember that you could get axle extenders that would screw in a similar fashion between the pedal and the crank for people with extra wide feet. They must have disappeared for a similar reason. Also people with wide feet often having 'wide' weight, worsening the mechanical problems.